How to set keymaps to ctrl+w in LunarVim
Why ?
I come from windows (specifically pycharm) and am really used to
ctrl+backspace

to delete whole words, Now i am switching to mac and neovim and am finding it really hard not having that.
The question
I found that there is a replacement to this, namely
ctrl+w

and i want to set it to
command+delete

is there any way to do this?
Sorry if this question has been already asked i could not find any solutions anywhere (also i am pretty new to Neovim)
Any feedback is appreciated

There is already a built in shortcut in vim to delete a whole word. The motion is "diw".
d(elete) -> i(n) -> w(ord)
If you are just getting started with vim, I would highly recommend this playlist by theprimagen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6AR2RMB5tE&list=PLm323Lc7iSW_wuxqmKx_xxNtJC_hJbQ7R&ab_channel=ThePrimeagen
If you must use that shorcut, here is how you could remap it in your nvim config
vim.keymap.set({ 'n', 'v' }, '<C-BS>', 'diw', { silent = true, desc = "deletes the word that the cursor is on" })

vim.keymap.set({ 'i }, '<C-BS>', '<C-W>', { silent = true, desc = "deletes the previous word in insert mode" })

I will add that the google search "ctrl backspace shortcut nvim" paired with "how to remap keys in neovim" would have gotten you the answer.

Thanks, i already know about ThePrimagen But that is not what i am looking for, i know this shortuct already but i am trying to find out if i can map it to ctrl+delete as i am used to ctrl+backspace from windows
Thanks tho

ok, here is an example of how you could do it. I edited my answer

Thank you very much, i did google "ctrl backspace shortcut nvim" and how to remap keys in neovim" after seeing your post and that indeed would have given me my answer , so apologies for having posted it on stackoverflow . Regardless, the code you shared worked perfectly thank you

No problem,
I would recommend always trying to find the answer on google for at least 30min before you ask on stackOverflow. Even if you don't find the answer to your question in that time, you likely learn more about the subject you are asking about. This will also improve your ability to ask the right questions and do the right searches to find things yourself or to help find things for others in the future
